How to automatically create a page from a link
I am using addnewpage templates to try to automatically create a sidebar for every new namespace directory.
Currently, I just make a link .:sidebar?do=edit&rev=&newpagetemplate=:templates:template2 This is working well, but I would rather the link instantly makes the page instead of opening the edit window. Is there anyway to make this fully automated or atleast remove the need to press "save" everytime?
